# Use fragment twice in same layout

Tags: android

Is it possible to reuse a fragment twice in one layout? I have a layout of two tabs, Tab A and Tab B.. each tab displays a view that consists of a list (of type A or B) of items on the left and the details of the selected item on the right. The "detail view" (on the right pane) is the same for both types of lists, so I want to have it remain while the list is swapped out depending on what tab is selected.

I have tried to include the details fragment in layout XML for both tabs but get a runtime error about duplicates. So then I tried to add them dynamically at runtime with a FragmentTransaction but get a similar error (fragment has already been added).

Is what i want to do possible?

Comment: Why cant you make two different layouts?

Comment: I could do that.. but it would be a lot of code duplication. This details fragment is identical for both types of lists. That's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: What about using different android:id for the different layout widgets? Have you tried that?

Comment: I tried that -- the 'class' attribute is the same for both and causes the error still.

Answer (score 4):

You should add the `fragments` dynamically setting different `TAGs` for each fragment and then finding them with `getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("TAG");` In each TAB view you can add a `FrameLayout` and then use `FragmentTransaction.replace` function.

I had a similar problem (adding the same `fragment` many times in a `ViewFlipper`) and solved it by using different tags.

Answer (score -4):

You could create duplicate classes. One from the other. And rename the second class to another name.

And set the second layout to

```
  class="name of second class"
```

Then rename the wigdets for use in the second renamed class that is identical to the first except different widget id's.

Comment: So then I'd have to duplicate the class... that is the code duplication I'm trying to avoid. I don't think it's possible though so I ended up going that route. Wasn't that much extra work...

Comment: And you could duplicate the class. You could just use different naming conventions(such as variables, and wigdet reference names). But seems like we've found the solution

Comment: Just to clarify for others,  like me,  browsing information  on this,  duplicating the class would be  absolutely nonsensical.