# Using the same Fragment class twice in different containers

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, containers

My question is pretty simple.... i have one container that i assign it with an instance of a fragment class.

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container2, new PlaceholderFragment2());
```

my question is can i use the same class in another container place under this one(i mean in the same activity)

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container2, new PlaceholderFragment2());
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container3, new PlaceholderFragment2());
```

Comment: I actually don't really know the answer, but I'm curious, although I see no reason why you shouldn't be able to, considering you ARE creating two different instances of the Fragment. Why not try it and see if it works?

Comment: actually i tried it and it seems like the fragment is removed from the first container(container2) and put in the second one(container3).

Comment: Interesting! Have you tried giving them a different tag?

Comment: i dont think it will make a difference givving them different tags, however i tried this and its not working

fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container2, new PlaceholderFragment2());


FrameLayout fl2 = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.container2);


fl2.setTag("frame2");


fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container22, new PlaceholderFragment2());


FrameLayout fl22 = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.container22);


fl22.setTag("frame22");

Comment: Do you commit the transactions before trying to add another instance of the Fragment to the other container?

Comment: nope... if i removed the second container (container22) i will have my work perfectly running and container2 will have the fragment shown

Comment: Did you google?  First answer in SO.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113928/use-fragment-twice-in-same-layout

Comment: Are you able to resolve this issue? I am facing the same :(

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Tnx. it work.